# Maven repository for Eclipse BIRT runtime

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, birt, m2eclipse

I'm trying to find a maven repo to allow me to add BIRT reporting dependencies to a Eclipse Dynamic Web project.

The closest I've found is http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/eclipse/birt/, but when that repo is added to the m2eclipse indexes, the BIRT artifacts are not found. As per http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.technology.m2e/msg00389.html (I'm not the author of the post there, that was just my source for the repo link)

I'm using, or trying to, BIRT 2.3.2

Comment: Anyone found a Maven repository for BIRT 2.6.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you defining your dependencies? and what types specifically are you looking for?

Looking at the repository, it contains the Birt jars and poms. If this is a standard Maven project you are able to declare the dependency as normal. So to reference core-api you should just have to do:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
  <artifactId>coreapi</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and ensure the repository is configured correctly in your settings or POM.

Can you post your POM and the trace from the build? it might help diagnose the problem.

Update: Based on your comment, it looks like the issue is that the JBoss Nexus index does not have the Birt projects on it. The dates for the index and both versions of Birt (all artifacts for 2.3.2 and 2.2.2) are both 8th July, and the index is only 83 minutes younger.

Creation of the Nexus index is [not automatic](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/M2ECLIPSE/Nexus+Indexer#NexusIndexer-indexer), so perhaps the indexer was run before the Birt artifacts were deployed and then published afterwards.

Comment: OK, that's plain weird. The Maven Indexes view doesn't list the BIRT artifacts, but adding the repo to the POM and pasting the snippet you have above does indeed pull in coreapi.

However, I'm trying to get the report-engine, so I can generate reports from within my webapp, and <artifactId>report-engine</artifactId> fails with "Missing artifact org.eclipse.birt:report-engine:jar:2.3.2:compile pom.xml", probably because the report-engine is packaged as a ZIP.

Numpty error on my part to be sure...

Comment: And adding <type>zip</type> manages to try to pull the artifact, waiting now (slow download) to see if it lets the build go through

Comment: I just ran this myself, I think there may be some intermittent issue with jboss serving up the files because it worked the second time with no changes

Comment: The ZIP gets downloaded OK but the classes within the file are not added to the build path. I suspect this ought to now be furthered on another question, something like "How do I get the BIRT report-engine maven artifact at <url> to be used for compile & deployed to servlet container", once I've dug in Google a bit.

Your comment above seems to suggest you managed to get a jar of the report-engine, but I don't see how that can be. I'll try though, just in case.

Comment: I only tried to download coreapi, not tried to do anything with the report-engine

Answer (score 1):

Below maven dependency worked for me perfectly.

```
    <repositories>
       <repository>
          <id>sonatype-nexus-releases</id>
          <name>Sonatype Nexus Releases</name>
          <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/</url>
       </repository>
     </repositories>
```

It worked for me for birt 3.7.1, try replacing version as per your need.

Thanks

Comment: Removed your unnecessary self-promotional link.